# Single quote problem in "sh -c" script launched from "find"

Tags: bash, find, quoting, ffmpeg

Now I am writing a script for a long time, but lately this problem has drives me crazy. I tried everything but couldn't solve it.

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -type f -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -c:a "$ACODEC" -c:v "$VCODEC" -vf \
    "subtitles={}.$SUBEXTE:'force_style=fontsize=$FSIZE,fontname=$FNAME'" \
"{}.$EXTE" -hide_banner \;
```

The idea is whenever `find` finds a mp4 file, do this `FFmpeg` commands. But when I want to try something more complex, like command substution for last variable `{}.$EXTE`, I have to use this syntax:

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -type f -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a "$2" -c:v "$3"\
 -vf "subtitles=$1.$4:'force_style=fontsize=$5,fontname=$6'" \
"$1.$7" -hide_banner' -- "{}" "$ACODEC" "$VCODEC" "$SUBEXTE" "$FSIZE" "$FNAME" "$EXTE" \;
```

As you see in this syntax when I use `sh -c`, I need to add extra single quotes `' '`. But this broke the `FFmpeg` code. I tried almost every possible variations; adding and removing single-double quotes and even tried backslashes.
Please help me! Some of the errors I got:

```
Unable to open ./sub.srt
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fffdb7d35e0] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args './sub.srt:force_style=fontsize='
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

```
And sometimes I got an error like not suitable format for fontname
```

Comment: Replace each internal single quote with `'\''`, if you really need single quotes there.

Comment: OMG!! You are life saver thank you sooo much. You don't know how many hours I spent this thing. Thank you again!

Comment: I don't understand how it worked tho :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single quoted string can never contain a single quote.

A solution to this conundrum would in your case be to replace each internal `'` in your in-line `sh -c` script with `'\''` (or `'"'"'`).

What this does is to

1. temporarily break out of the single quoted string (the first `'` in `'\''` ends the single quoted string),
2. insert a literal `'` (the `\'` in `'\''`, which you could also write as `"'"`, but that is *far* too many quotes and makes it unreadable), and then
3. concatenate that with the remaining original single quoted string (the final `'` in `'\''` starts a new single quoted string).

The `sh -c` command would then look like

```
sh -c '
ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a "$2" -c:v "$3" \
    -vf "subtitles=$1.$4:'\''force_style=fontsize=$5,fontname=$6'\''" \
    "$1.$7" -hide_banner' ...arguments as before ...
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand better.